# openerp default(first) page should be form view

Tags: openerp-7, formview, xmlformview

How to get openerp default(first) page as a form view

i have constructed a module in openerp framework and i need default(first) page should be "form view". how can we get form view with all previously saved data. i don't want tree/list view or kanban view. i need as shown in below image[image: FORM VIEW FORMAT]

i can get the form view but previously added data will be not visible. so as shown in the fig. can we do it. is there any method for that?